# rasa.core.processor - Encountered an exception while running action

Tags: python, python-3.x, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

Rasa, I'm getting the following error in rasa:

```
rasa.core.processor  - Encountered an exception while running action 'action_get_summary'. Bot will continue, but the actions events are lost. Make sure to fix the exception in your custom code.
```

Comment: Could you paste the logs from the action server?  Something may have gone wrong in your custom code.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it myself after reading through the error messages which I later got from using `-vv` as the switch in the command. Then ran the custom actions by specifying `--endpoints endpoints`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself after reading through the error messages which I later got from using 
`-vv` as the switch in the command.
Then ran the custom actions by specifying `--endpoints endpoints` switch in the commands.

So now, I ran 2 command in 2 separate terminals:

```
rasa interactive -vv --endpoints endpoints.yml   
rasa run -vv --endpoints endpoints actions
```